# LINQ to SQL: If I add a object to Linq Entity set doesn't it get added

Tags: linq-to-sql

Let's say I have a Company table and a Division table. Each Division has a Foreign key to a company so each company can have many Division children.

If I grab a Company object with Linq-to-sql I have a access to it's Divisions property, a entity set of Division objects. If I add a new Division object to it and call SubmitChanges() won't it automatically go into the Division table or am I forced to call InsertOnSubmit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to insert objects into the database with LINQ to SQL. For instance:

```
db.Divisions.InsertOnSubmit(new Division()
{
    Company = db.Company.Single(c => c.Id == 1),
    // other properties
});

db.SubmitChanges();
```

Or:

```
var company = db.Company.Single(c => c.Id == 1);

company.Divisions.Add(new Division()
{
    // other properties
});

db.SubmitChanges();
```

As you can see, you can use the `InsertOnSubmit` of the `Table<Division> Divisions` property on the data context, but you can also use the `Add` method of the `EntitySet<Division> Divisions` property on the `Company` entity. They both do -about- the same. Nice about the latter approach is that you don't need to 'link' the company to the new division, because LINQ to SQL can figure that out for you.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes I see where I wen't wrong. The changes only happened to a wrapper areound the EntitySet, never to the set itself.

Comment: @Pleun: I'm sorry, but your statement is false. You don't need `InsertOnSubmit` after calling `Add` with LINQ to SQL. Please try it out.